# Changing the color of a box on click with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

New to js and could use some help. I have been trying to change the color of the box after clicking the button blue. Can I just use js to change the box color or do I need some css magic?

```js
$("#btn1").on("click", function() {
  $("#box").animate({
    height: "+=35px",
    width: "+=35px"
  }, "fast");
})

$("#btn2").on("click", function() {
  $("box")({
    backgroundColor: "blue"
  });
})

$("#btn3").on("click", function() {
  $("#box").fadeOut();
})

$("#btn4").on("click", function() {
  $("#box").animate({
    height: "150px",
    width: "150px"
  }, "fast");
  $("#box").fadeIn(), "fast";

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>

<div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:pink; margin:25px;"></div>

<button id="btn1">Grow</button>
<button id="btn2">Blue</button>
<button id="btn3">Fade</button>
<button id="btn4">Reset</button>
```

Comment: You're missing [something](http://api.jquery.com/css/) in this line: `$("box")({backgroundColor:"blue"});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Heretic Monkey hinted at missing code, as Guzz mentioned you are missing the method `.css()` and as Rafv mentioned, your selector is wrong is it should be `$('#box')`. I'll go one step further in the spirit of the code and animate the color change:

```
$("#box").animate().css({
  backgroundColor: "blue"
}, 2500);
```

and more importantly add this to the CSS:

```
#box {
  transition: background-color 2.5s ease-out
}
```

As a bonus, the reset function is rewritten so that the **[methods are chained](https://www.learningjquery.com/2016/10/using-method-chaining-in-jquery)** and arranged so that each animation can be seen in reverse.

```
...
  $("#box").fadeIn("fast").animate({
    height: "150px",
    width: "150px"
  }, "fast").css({
    backgroundColor: "pink"
  }, 1500);
...
```

---

### Demo

```js
$("#btn1").on("click", function() {
  $("#box").animate({
    height: "+=35px",
    width: "+=35px"
  }, "fast");
});

$("#btn2").on("click", function() {
  $("#box").animate().css({
    backgroundColor: "blue"
  }, 2500);
});

$("#btn3").on("click", function() {
  $("#box").fadeOut();
});

$("#btn4").on("click", function() {
  $("#box").fadeIn("fast").animate({
    height: "150px",
    width: "150px"
  }, "fast").css({
    backgroundColor: "pink"
  }, 1500);
});
```

```css
#box {
  transition: background-color 2.5s ease-out
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>

<div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:pink; margin:25px;"></div>

<button id="btn1">Grow</button>
<button id="btn2">Blue</button>
<button id="btn3">Fade</button>
<button id="btn4">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for the wonderful tips and tricks! I will be sure to use. Thank you so much for the wonderful help!

Comment: Glad I could help. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Your jquery function should be:

```
$("box").css({backgroundColor:"blue"});
```

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

You missing `#` in `box` section and for non-multiple css, better use

```
$("#box").css("background-color", "blue");
```

> css("propertyname","value");

More about this [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp).